# Adding Legend on a basic chart

Tags: javascript, charts

I am brand new to d3.js and stackoverflow so please pardon if I ask something very basic. I have a basic donut chart however it is a modification of a normal donut chart since you can see there is one on top of another. I was wondering if it is possible to add a label right on the chart. I am able to add legend and label outside the chart but i want to be able to add a label right on the chart itself.

This is the code for chart

```
var dataset = {
  data1: [53245, 28479, 19697, 24037, 40245],
  data2: [53245, 28479, 19697, 24037, 40245]
};

var width = 460,
    height = 300,
    cwidth = 45;

var color = d3.scale.category20();

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
    .sort(null);

var arc = d3.svg.arc();

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

var gs = svg.selectAll("g").data(d3.values(dataset)).enter().append("g");
var path = gs.selectAll("path")
    .data(function(d) { return pie(d); })
  .enter().append("path")
    .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i); })
    .attr("d", function(d, i, j) { return arc.innerRadius(10+cwidth*j).outerRadius(cwidth*(j+1))(d); });
```

This is the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nk695uq7/). I would highly be pleased with any suggestions to be able to add label and legend. I would want label to be on top of both the charts in the fiddle.

Comment: Have you seen [this tutorial](http://zeroviscosity.com/d3-js-step-by-step/step-3-adding-a-legend)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for? [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3obc8bLj/).

Essentially what this does is append a text element which is positioned using the angle of the path element.

```
var angle = d.endAngle - d.startAngle;
var loc = d.startAngle - (Math.PI/2) + (angle/2);
return Math.sin(loc) * radius;
```

If you want the labels on the left side to not overlap onto the chart you could use something similar to the following

```
var textLength = [];
gEnter.selectAll("text").each(function () {
    textLength.push(this.getComputedTextLength());
});
```

To get the lengths of the text objects, then you can modify either `.attr("x", ...)` or `.attr("transform", "translate(x,0)")` when `d.startAngle` is greater than PI (meaning that it is on the left side of the chart), subtracting the text length from the x element to position it further left.

Comment: Hi, This is kind of what i was looking for except you see how your text is going over the bar i was wondering if it is possible for it to stay inside and i wanted to add a legend with it. What source did you use to get this result?

Comment: i upvoted you but can you help me with something simlar to the link i posted @JSBob

Comment: Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3obc8bLj/1/) with some things added. If you're looking for something exactly like in that image you'll have to change the layout of the input data to include both values and categories (USA, Japan, Australia) and then load that in. With this you could also generate the outer pi chart dynamically (by summing the values from the first array and grouping by category).

Comment: This is awesome! so is it possible to update this chart by loading real time data?@JSBob